# What does it mean: JavaFX application class must extend javafx.application.Application?

Tags: java, javafx

What is meant by this error:

> Error: Main method not found in class Static.A, please define the main
>   method as:
>          public static void main(String[] args)
>       or a JavaFX application class must extend javafx.application.Application

I was trying to run a program Without main Method..

```
public class A
{
    static
    {
      System.out.println("Hello");
      System.exit(0);
     }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to run your program either you should have the `main` method or if it is a JavaFX application then you have to have the `start` method.
According to your class, you don't have neither of the conditions. So that is why you get the error

Answer (score 0):

This means you don't have a main method in your class as the error says. Replace the `static` with `public static void main(String[] args)` and it works. Also it is not possible to run a program without a main method.

Comment: "it is not possible to run a program without main method" is not actually true. From the [`java` tool documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html#BGBCIEFC): "The `java` command can be used to launch a JavaFX application by loading a class that **either** has a `main()` method **or** that extends `javafx.application.Application`." (My emphasis.)